# Overlaps function in GeoPandas/GeoSeries is not working

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geometry, geopandas, geoseries

There seems to be wrong with the `overlaps` function. Suppose I have this GeoDataFrame consisting of LineString geometries only with `crs='EPSG:3347`:

[image]

Then I went ahead to extract only the first row's LineString, and put in a GeoSeries format as follows:

[image]

And then used the `overlaps` function. But it gives the wrong result. The first row in the output is False when it should have been True since they are merely the same LineString. So I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that geometry1 is the same than geometry2 then they do not overlap. See the literal explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM

> **a overlaps b**: they have some but not all points in common, they have
> the same dimension, and the intersection of the interiors of the two
> geometries has the same dimension as the geometries themselves

Comment: Ah I see, I could be wrong. Maybe `overlaps` is not the correct function I need. I need a function that works like `intersects` but the intersections should only be LineStrings or MultiLineStrings. Do you know what is the right function to use? I could create a column that determines the intersections first and then another column for determining if it contains 'LineString' in its name, but I think it's rather slow.

Comment: I would go with the logic of "a intersects b AND the geometry type of intersection(a,b) is not point".